# Replace first four characters of a string

Tags: regex, sed, replace, mask

I would need to mask, with Regular Expression in Sed Editor, a string after 4 characters.

Example: 1234567890
Result: 1234XXXXXX

Can you help me?

Comment: Is the length of the string always going to be the same (10 characters in this case)?

Comment: could your text contain spaces?

Answer (score 2):

In GNU sed:

```
echo "1234567890" | sed "s/./X/5g"
```

Comment: Notice that the behaviour for `/5g` is GNU sed specific.

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may help you here.

```
echo "1234567890" | awk '{for(i=5;i<=length($0);i++){val=val?val "X":"X"};print substr($0,1,4) val;val=""}'
```

Output will be as follows.

```
1234XXXXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$echo "1234567890"|awk '{for(i=5;i<=NF;i++)$i="X"}7' FS="" OFS=""
1234XXXXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

With perl, you can put arbitrary perl code in the replacement text:

```
perl -pe 's/^(....)(.*)/$1 . "X" x length($2)/e' <<END
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
12345678
123456789
1234567890
END
```

```
1
12
123
1234
1234X
1234XX
1234XXX
1234XXXX
1234XXXXX
1234XXXXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

With sed

```
count=4
echo "1234567890" | \
sed ':A;s/\(\(.\)\{'"$count"'\}\)\(X*\)[^X]/\1\3X/;tA'
```

or

```
sed -E ':A;s/((.){'"$count"'})(X*)[^X]/\1\3X/;tA'
```